# What alternatives to IPSec for diversifyed redundancy?

Tags: ipsec

I need to provide redundancy to an IPSec link between two premises. I would like to have no single point of failure and to diversify technologies. What could I use please?

Are the following leads possible:

- HTTPS link encrypted using PKI
- 4G link

Comment: This looks more like a network design question than a security question.

Comment: With security in mind, I raised myself the same question and could not answer.

Comment: @schroeder of course, feel free to move it if it is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to provide redundancy between sites, you're right that a TLS would be a viable solution for an extra security protocol and a 4G connection has the potential to be a form of redundancy for the site-to-site connection.

Your question isn't really clear on what you're asking for specifically, because HTTPS and 4G work on entirely different levels. If you're talking about **protocol** redundancy, depending on your use case, you could easily use another encryption technology such as TLS or SSH to connect the two sites. If you're wanting **connection** redundancy I'd recommend using a secondary line from a different ISP or like you said, a 4G connection to maintain the connectivity in the event of your VPN having downtime. Obviously you can combine the two since, like I said, they work on entirely different levels. For example; you can get a 4G connection and use TLS over it.

Comment: Actually both of them

Comment: I believe the answer does cover "both", in the last sentence.